# Apply texture coordinates from material in Cycles to UV

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, texture-coordinates

I'm making a fake Hollywood/LA setting, which has required the use of a [Stucco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stucco) material. Lots of Stucco.

Rather than go through each building object and ensure that the UVs for each material represents a uniform size, I can just automatically do this by setting the material up in Cycles, and tying it's Texture Coordinate to Object position, with Box Projection.

...and that's how far I've gotten. I want to export my scene to another application, so in order to retain the uniform mapping, I need to apply it to a UV Channel/Object. This would leave me with entirely uniform results, room to adjust individual surfaces from this point, and thus hours of material and UV management between separate building objects saved.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Just tried, and found that the "cube projection" UV mapping option produces different results to the generated box texture projection in cycles. If that difference is a dealbreaker, I think you're going to have to do it the hard way.

Comment: @dixiepig I'm a little confused about what you mean - you mean `Edit Mode > U (key) > Cube Projection`? Yeah, I know this option exists - it's just not the same as Cycle's object-based texture coords. I want to know how to transfer the generated Texture Coordinates from Cycles to actual UV - surely Blender is calculating this data, so it has to exist in some form that can put into plain UVs.

Comment: On Cube Projection: Its problem is that you have no centralized control, and thus no way to use it on multiple objects/surfaces effectively or uniform. It does appear to produce a similar type of result based on the environment, but in addition to no control central variable, it cannot be propagated across several objects as the Cycles material does. I'm just hoping there's a way to centralize control, in the least. In the end I could go through each and use the same scale variable (or automate that), but if it's possible to do it through the material I would like to know.